# Good way to use and test local packages in Google App Engine apps written in golang?

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I have a problem of testing my GAE golang app uses local packages.
The probject looks something like this.

```
.
├── app.yaml
├── main.go
└── handler
    └── handler.go
```

`handler` package is imported in `main.go`.

```
package main

import "handler"
```

Everything (e.g., `goapp serve`) works fine until I started writing tests.
`goapp test` complains that `handler` package is not found. Seems like `GOPATH`
of `goapp serve` and `goapp test` are different. One solution I found is to put
`handler` package outside of the project path and import it with fully
qualified name (e.g., `github.com/.../handler`) but it doesn't make sense to me
to split the project in to separate places where they're tightly coupled. Are
there any good way to use and test local packages?

Following resources are found on this topic.

- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine-go/C_i5kQEi7-A
- https://github.com/matthewbelisle-wf/gopath-problem

Comment: try to create an app folder and move app.yaml and main.go  
this is how i used to work with app engine and go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This comes late, but if anyone runs into the same issue, here is how to deal with it:

1. Organize your code this way

   ```
   /whereever
   └── /myproject
       └──/src
          ├── app.yaml
          ├── main.go
          └── /handler
              └── handler.go
   ```
2. Use unqualified imports for your project code e.g.

   ```
   import handler
   ```
3. Run `goapp serve` and `goapp deploy` from inside the src folder. serve/deploy work relative to the app.yaml

   ```
   cd /whereever/myproject/src
   goapp serve
   ```
4. Set GOPATH  for `goapp test` , it work based on GOPATH

   ```
   cd /whereever/myproject    #GOPATH expects a subfolder called src
   GOPATH=$GOPATH:`pwd`       #add the current folder to the GOPATH
   goapp test ./...           #run all tests in any subfolders
   ```
5. Reset your GOPATH if necessary

   ```
   source ~/.profile #this assumes ~/.profile is where you have permanently set your GOPATH
   ```

All in all, "working as intended", but still a pain.

Answer (score 1):

You need to import handler with a fully qualified name, however you don't need to move it out of the project to do so.  If your project folder looks like this:

```
/go
└── /myproject
    ├── app.yaml
    ├── main.go
    └── /handler
        └── handler.go
```

Then your handler import should look like this:

```
import "myproject/handler"
```

Comment: The problem is that putting the project inside the GOPATH and import handler with a fully qualified name causes the import conflict. The error message is `go-app-builder: Failed parsing input: app file handler.go conflicts with same file imported from GOPATH`.

Comment: This does not work, still complains with `cannot find package "myproject/x" in any of...`

Comment: Make sure the `x.go` file has `package x` rather than `package main`.

Comment: go doc for the package will tell you the import path to use for it - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/58754175/1569204