# golang modules and local packages

Tags: go, module

I'm trying to understand how to organize my golang project using go1.11 modules. I tried several options, but none of them worked.

I have some code in the main package under the application folder and a local package that the main package uses.

```
$GOPATH
+ src
  + application/
    + main/
      + main.go
      + otherFileUnderMainPackage.go
    + aLocalPackage/
      + someCode.go
      + someCode_test.go
      + someMoreCode.go
      + someMoreCode_test.go
```

Files in the main package, imports `../aLocalPackage`. When I compile by `go build main/*.go` it's working.

Then, I ran `go mod init application: V.0.9.9` and got the go.mod file, but the build always fails. I always get error about not finding the local package: `build application:V0.9.9/main: cannot find module for path _/.../src/application/aLocalPackage`. I also tried to place the local package right under src/, place it under main/ etc. but none of these methods worked for me.

What is the way to use modules and local packages?

Thanks.

Comment: Don't use relative imports.

Comment: Did that too. got an error. I changed the import to `application/aLocalPackage` and got `cannot find module for path application/aLocalPackage`

Comment: Where is you go.mod? Show its content. Note that "module builds" inside GOPATH are off by default. Read go help modules.

Comment: go.mod is under `application/`. its content is just `module application` + some requires.
I did run `export GO111MODULE=on`

Comment: It's working for me now, kind of... I can't use prometheus client with vgo (some packages are not loaded) so I dropped vgo from my project for now. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Can you explain what is vgo is?

Comment: vgo was adopted into golang 1.11: https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules

Comment: Ah, Russ' demo implementation!. No need to use vgo anymore.

Answer (score 2):

I had some problems working with local packages myself. 
There are two tricks to make it work:

1. you run "go build" in the package directory

This compiles the package and places it in the build cache.
This link about [code organisation in go](https://golang.org/doc/code.html) explains more.
You can identify where the cache is using:

```
>go env GOCACHE
/home/<user>/.cache/go-build
```

2. Import using a path relative to the project

I puzzled loads over what the correct import path was and finally discovered that `go doc` or `go list` will tell you.

```
>go doc
package docs // import "tools/src/hello/docs"
>go list
tools/src/hello/docs
```

For example. I have a hello world API project and was using [swaggo](https://github.com/swaggo) to generate documentation which it does in a `docs` sub-directory.
To use it I add an import:

```
_ "tools/src/hello/docs"
```

For my case the _ is important as docs is not used directly but we its init() function to be invoked.

Now in `hello/main.go` I can add `"tools/src/hello/docs"` and it will import the correct package.

The path is relative to the location of go.mod if you have one.
I have tools/ here as I have a go.mod declaring "modules tools".

Modules are a different kettle of fish - see https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules.
Recent versions of go (1.11 and later) can create a `go.mod` file which you may use to fix the version of a module that is used and avoid go's crazy default behaviour of just downloading the latest version of any package you import.

Comment: You might find this blog interesting. https://marcofranssen.nl/manage-go-tools-via-go-modules/ that is how I managed in some of my projects.

Answer (score 1):

Relative import paths are not supported in module mode. You will need to update your `import` statements to use a full (absolute) import path.

You should also choose a module name other than `application`. Your module path should generally begin with a URL prefix that you control — either your own domain name, or a unique path such as `github.com/$USER/$REPO`.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a blogpost on how to start your first Go project using modules.

https://marcofranssen.nl/start-on-your-first-golang-project/

In general it boils down to just create a new folder somewhere on your system (doesn't have to be in GOPATH).

```sh
mkdir my-project
cd my-project
go mod init github.com/you-user/my-project
```

This will create the go.mod file. Now you can simply create your project layout and start building whatever you like.

Maybe one of my other blogs can inspire you a bit more on how to do things.

https://marcofranssen.nl/categories/software-development/golang/